# Modify HTML output of Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

By default my django ModelForm generates an HTML form. I'd like to modify the HTML output of the form by including an extra attribute in the `select` element:

```
# models.py
class FoodForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ('name', 'ingredients')

# default HTML output
<form action="/" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
        <input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="id_ingredients">Ingredients:</label> 
        <select multiple="multiple" name="ingredients" id="id_ingredients">
        <option value="1">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="2">Cottage cheese</option>
        <option value="3">Onion</option>
```

I'd like to **add a new attribute** to the select field and **leave the current attributes untouched**:

```
# desired HTML output
<select multiple="multiple" name="ingredients" id="id_ingredients" data-placeholder="Choose ingredients...">
```

I tried to do it with widgets (see below) but it gives me an error:

```
class FoodForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ('name', 'ingredients')
        widgets = {
            'ingredients': Select(attrs={'data-placeholder': "Choose ingredients..."}),
        }

# NameError: name 'Select' is not defined
```

Any ideas how to modify the HTML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the widget [from `django.forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#select):

```
from django import forms
class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ('name', 'ingredients')
        widgets = {
            'ingredients': forms.Select(attrs={'data-placeholder': "Choose ingredients..."}),
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there some easy way to just add the new attribute? The current solution replaces all attributes with the one specified in widgets. I could of course just explicitly define each attribute but is there some better way?

Answer (score 1):

You only forgot to `from django.forms.widgets import Select`